How to understand why the two period Differences-in-Differences estimator is the ATT estmator?
I read in a paper here that in a two time period differences-in-differences scenario where it claims the DiD estimator is the ATT (Average Treatment on Treated). I am trying to understand why that is. Denote the two time periods by $t^*$ and $t^* - 1$ and define a treatment indicator $D_i$, so that $D_i = 1$ for units that participate in the treatment and $D_i = 0$ for units that do not participate in the treatment.
Next, for $t \in \{t^* - 1, t^*\}$, define $Y_{it}(1)$ to be unit $i$'s treated potential outcome in time period $t$ (this is the outcome that it would experience if it were in the treated group), and define $Y_{it}(0)$ to be unit $i$'s untreated potential outcome in time period $t$ (this is the outcome that it would experience if it were in the untreated group).
The paper states that
$$
\text{ATT} = E[Y_{t^*}(1) - Y_{t^*}(0) \mid D = 1]
$$
There is an existing post here which discusses it, but I feel it fails to explain it intuitively.
It seems that in the DiD scenario, there is a treated and a control group at time $t^*$, since one got the treatment, and the other didn't. It therefore seems strange to talk about them being both treated. How can I think about this?

To try some intuition: What DiD does is infer a treatment effect by comparing the change for the treated group with the change for the untreated group. The parallel trends assumption tells us that the change for the untreated group is the change we would have seen for the treated group had it not been treated.
In other words, we do as if/hope that the control group can serve as benchmark for what would have happened to the treatment group in the absence of treatment. Since, in many applications of DiD, the treatment and control groups differ in many respects (although as per the parallel trends assumption not in how they change over time in the absence of treatment), we get an ATT.
